# can i run simple c++ command line scripts on my iphone?

Tags: c++, ios

I would like to run some math code that I have been working on for a while on my iPhone. I use nothing but cin, cout, and getline. I also use a fair bit of the stl.

Comment: I assume you mean the standard library, not the STL.

Comment: There's been a boom of _offline_ C++ compilers for iOS recently. Just search for 'compiler' in the AppStore. You can also jailbreak your iDevice and compile & run fully featured C++ programs.

Comment: Please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script and do not call a c++ program script next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [cloud9](https://c9.io) the web based programming environment. It supports c++. All you need is a web browser.